# How to specify an id for an Html.LabelFor?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

The code looks like this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FormModel.Position, Model.Company.DefaultEmployee.ToStringOrDefault())
```

And the HTML looks like this:

`<label for="FormModel.Position" >Programmer</label>`
("Programmer" is the string generated by the `Model.Company.DefaultEmployee.ToStringOrDefault()` method)

I tried this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FormModel.Position, Model.Company.DefaultEmployee.ToStringOrDefault(), new {id = "position-label"})
```

But it does not work.

This is what the Html extension looks like:

```
 public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string labelText, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return LabelFor(html, expression, labelText, new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
    }
```

Comment: Using `new {id = "position-label"}` works just fine (unless your still using MVC-2). What makes you think it does not work?

Comment: I get an error saying that the call is ambiguous between
`LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string labelText, object htmlAttributes)`
and
`LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string labelText, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)`

Comment: What your claiming does not make sense. You have said the 1st snippet generates `<label for="FormModel.Position" style="padding:0">Model.Company.DefaultEmployee.ToStringOrDefault()</label>` - where does the `style="padding:0"` come from? And the text will not be `Model.Company.DefaultEmployee.ToStringOrDefault()` - it will be the string generated by that method. What is your `.ToStringOrDefault()` method and what is its output?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to take the padding out. While I was waiting for an answer i just wrote the label as <label ...>....</label> instead of Html.LabelFor(...) so that I can make some modifications to it. As for  Model.Company.DefaultEmployee.ToStringOrDefault() it generates "Programmer", but I thought that it would be a bit confusing if I just wrote "Programmer" instead of that method, but maybe I should have just written that it generates "Programmer". So, in other words, the generated HTML looks like this: `<label for="FormModel.Position">Programmer</label>`. Sorry for all the confusion.